# How can count the number of links in a page using xslt?

Tags: xml

```
<a>
<b>
<html:p><html:a>link1</html:a><html:a>link2</html:a></html:p></b></a>
```

How to get the count of the links?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all html:a nodes whereever they are (not just the ones in your example)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(//html:a)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can count the links by using the object node. 
Try this - `<xsl:value-of select="count(/root/*)"/>`